# ¿Es posible leer el contenido de un archivo sin mantenerlo en memoria?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy trabajando con el scanner de un interprete que estoy realizando, pero me encuentro con que la clase `StreamReader` se torna un poco lenta con archivos algo pesados, hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
abstract class Scanner
{
    // Campos...
    private char[] Input;

    public virtual IList<Token> Scan()
    {
        // Código para escanear.
        return Tokens;
    }

    public Scanner(string _path, bool _debug)
    {
        // ...
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_path))
            Input = sr.ReadToEnd().ToCharArray(); // Lee todo el archivo y lo convierte a un char[].
    }
}
```

Mi problema es el siguiente, ¿Existe algúna manera de no tener que leer el archivo completo y convertirlo en un array de `char` para usarlo a lo largo del escaneo? Lo que busco es leer el archivo, devolver el siguiente caracter y cerrar el archivo sin mantenerlo en memoria y recordando la posición del ultimo carácter leído.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu mejor opción es `StreamReader` el problema es el método que estás usando.  `ReadToEnd` lee el archivo completo antes de continuar, en vez de esto puedes intentar con [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        // analizar la línea actual
    }
}
```

Esto procesa las líneas una a la vez.  Claro que este método te servirá solo si tienes un archivo separado por cambios de línea (`"\n"`).  Si necesitas más control sobre como se lee el archivo, tienes disponible el método [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que es más avanzado.

---

Lo que comentas es que necesitas cerrar y abrir el archivo en la última posición, entonces puedes hacer algo así:

```
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("")) {
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(_lastPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                if ( /* alguna condición para detener la lectura */) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            _lastPosition = reader.BaseStream.Position;
        }
```

Necesitas almacenar la última posición en el archivo pero ten en cuenta que si estás escribiendo en el archivo entre lectura y lectura, la posición puede no ser la misma de antes.

Comment: Pero `StreamReader` mantiene el archivo cargado en memoria, no? Lo que necesito es dejar de usar el archivo cuando no lo necesite y reanudar la lectura en el caracter que he dejado.

Comment: No, `StreamReader` no va a cargar el archivo completo en memoria,  el *reader* utiliza internamente un buffer, lee un fragmento a la vez (aun cuando usas `ReadToEnd`).

Comment: Pero lo que dices es que quieres poder cerrar y volver a abrir el archivo en una posición, cierto? entonces actualizaré la respuesta

Comment: El update me convence más, voy a probarlo y te cuento mis experiencias!